# Как создать на странице кнопки и счетчик к ней на php+html

Tags: php, html

Хотел бы узнать, как можно создать кнопку, а рядом с ней выводить текст "Вы нажали на кнопку n раз".

```
<?php
$num = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['but'])){
        $num++;
        echo'Вы нажали на кнопку '.$num.' раз';
    }
?>
<form action="registration.php" method="post">
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Жми' name='but'>
</form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть какая нибудь другая функция проверяющая, нажата ли кнопка и можно ли этот пример реализовать с помощью куки/рекурсии

```
<?php
$num=0;
setcookie('click', $_POST['but']);
if(isset($_COOKIE['click'])){
    echo 'Вы нажали на кнопку '.$num.' раз';
    $num++;
}
?>
<form action="registration.php" method="post">
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Жми' name='but'>
</form>
```

Вот попытка сделать тоже самое через куки, выводит только 0(из $num)

Comment: "и можно ли этот пример реализовать с помощью куки/рекурсии" --- для PHP именно куки и нужны. по-другому никак. для js - ничего не нужно (если не нужно хранить состояние после перезагрузки)

Comment: С помощью куки у меня к сожалению тоже не получилось, не обновляется считчик, как стоял на 0(в $num. так и стоит)

Comment: Покажите весь код. как сохраняете в куки, как выводите и т.д.

Comment: добавил код в тело вопроса, подскажите пожалуйста, если сможете

Comment: в куках надо хранить как раз таки количество раз. а сейчас просто проверяется кука, а счётчик увеличивается у num=0; Надо проверять - был пост запрос и нет куки - тогда поставить со значением  1. Был пост запрос и есть кука: взять данные из куки, увеличить на 1 и записать опять в куку....попутно отобразив юзеру итог

Comment: А какая функция проверяет, был запрос или нет? Не могли бы вы полностью написать этот код?

Comment: `setcookie('click', (isset($_COOKIE["click"]) ? ++$_COOKIE["click"] : 1));`

Comment: @yellow_pus если POST не пустой и содержит необходимые данные., например, что там есть имя but.- значит был запрос

Comment: Ну мужики, просто мне это не для какого либо проекта/работы/дипломной, мне это для себя, для того чтобы понять, как работать с куки и формами. Напишите пожалуйста полностью ответ, я правда, искал похожий вопрос в интернете, но его нет

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам php для этих целей, если вы состояние не собираетесь на сервере хранить?

```js
const $b = document.getElementById('b');
let value = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(`value`) ?? 0);

$b.innerText = `Нажвтий: ${value}`;
$b.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  value++;
  $b.innerText = `Нажвтий: ${value}`;
});
```

```html
<button id="b"></button>
```

Если нужно решение на чистом php, то можно сделать так:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$num = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'clicked', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ?? 0;
if (!is_int($num)) $num = 0;

if (array_key_exists('but', $_POST)) {
    $num++;
    setcookie('click', $num);
}

echo 'Вы нажали на кнопку ' . $num . ' раз';
$num++;
?>
<form action="registration.php" method="post">
    <input type='submit' value='Жми' name='but'>
</form>
```